# Custom UICollectionViewCell with UIProgressView shows progressView on reused cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am subclassing `UICollectionViewCell` because I wanted to add a `UIImageView` and a `UIProgressView` to the cell:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        // ImageView
        _imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        _imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        _imageView.layer.borderWidth = 0.7;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_imageView];

        // Progress View
        _progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
        _progressView.frame = CGRectMake(5, self.bounds.size.height - 20, self.bounds.size.width - 10, 10);
        _progressView.hidden = YES;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_progressView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

When I touch a cell and it calls `collectionView:didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` I set `cell.progressView.hidden = NO;` and start my download and updating of the `progressView`.

But, as I scroll that cell is reused and the `progressView` is shown on other cells. I have tried a number of different things to only show it on the correct cell, but nothing I have tried is working.

**Is there a better way to do this such as doing something in `prepareForReuse`?**

**EDIT: Full methods as requested**

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PUCViewpointItem *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PUCImageGridCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CollectionViewCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.imageURLHigh] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PUCDefaultBackground.png"]];

    // See if we have the file already
    if (![self.itemPaths objectForKey:item.name]) {
        cell.imageView.alpha = 0.4;
    } else {
        cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0;
    }

    // See if we are downloading
    if (![self.progressItems objectForKey:item.name]) {
        cell.progressView.hidden = YES;
    } else {
        cell.progressView.hidden = NO;
    }

    return cell;
}


- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PUCViewpointItem *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PUCImageGridCell *cell = (PUCImageGridCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    // File Path
    NSString *path = [self itemPath:item];
    if (!path) {

        // Set the indexPath we are downloading
        [self.progressItems setObject:indexPath forKey:item.name];

        Utility *utility = [[Utility alloc] init];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.url]];
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        NSString *localPath = [[utility localDirectory] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@.pdf", item.name];
        operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:localPath append:NO];

        [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

            float totalProgress = (float)totalBytesRead/(float)totalBytesExpectedToRead;
            if ([[collectionView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]) {
                cell.progressView.alpha = 1.0;
                cell.progressView.progress = totalProgress;
            }

        }];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            // This section seems to not get called or updated correctly when the cell 
            // that is showing the activityView is offscreen
            if ([[collectionView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]) {
                [self.itemPaths setObject:localPath forKey:item.name];
                [self.progressItems removeObjectForKey:item.name];
                cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0;
                cell.progressView.alpha = 0.0;
            }

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self.progressItems removeObjectForKey:item.name];
            cell.progressView.alpha = 0.0;
        }];

        [operation start];

    } else {

        [self readIssueAtPath:path];

    }

}//end
```

Comment: cellForItemAtIndexPath creates and configures the cell for one specific index path. What do you mean by "... on all the other cells"?

Comment: I realize that. I mean it isn't hiding on the other cells that are returned from that method.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have difficulties to understand the problem. For each cell that comes into appearance, cellForItemAtIndexPath should be called and show or hide the progress bar. What are the "other cells"?

Comment: Try set [cell setNeedsDisplay:YES] before returning all the cells in the method collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:

Comment: Not sure why this is hard to understand. The "other cells" meaning the cells that should not be showing the `progressView`.

Comment: In didSelectItemAtIndexPath, you're setting a value on the cell rather than in your model, whereas in the cellForItemAtIndexPath: method, you're inspecting what I presume is your model (self.progressItems).

Comment: Correct, but when `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` is called I have `[self.progressItems setObject:indexPath forKey:item.name];` to set it in my model.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the full methods for didSelectItemAtIndexPath: and cellForItemAtIndexPath:. It's not clear why you would expect [self.progressItems objectForKey:item.name] to be different for different cells, since there's no indexPath associated with it.

Comment: K, just added the full methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information whether a download is in progress for a certain item or not should be stored
in some *data source* (or *model*) and not in the cell (the *view*).

Then you can update the cell's appearance in the data source delegate method `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` according to the status of the item at that index
path and show or hide the progress view of the cell.

**ADDED:** The progress, completion and failure block all capture the current cell.
Therefore they will modify this cell even if it has been reused for a different index path.
To solve that, you can check if the cell's (current) index path is still equal
to the original (captured) index path:

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

    float totalProgress = (float)totalBytesRead/(float)totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    if ([[collectionView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]) {
       cell.progressView.alpha = 1.0;
       cell.progressView.progress = totalProgress;
    }
}];
```

and similar for the completion and failure block:

```
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [self.itemPaths setObject:localPath forKey:item.name];
    [self.progressItems removeObjectForKey:item.name];
    if ([[collectionView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]) {
        cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0;
        cell.progressView.alpha = 0.0;
    }

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    [self.progressItems removeObjectForKey:item.name];
    if ([[collectionView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]) {
        cell.progressView.alpha = 0.0;
    }
}];
```

Comment: I have been doing that, just didn't post it here since it wasn't working for me. See my edits above.

Comment: @NicHubbard: After staring at your code for some time, I had another idea what might be the problem. I have updated the answer, but the code is not compiler checked. - I hope that helps!

Comment: That actually solved the issue with the `activityView` being reused, which is good news! But now, a sid-effect of this is that when the completion block is called, it seems to not know which cell it was downloading, IF I have scrolled that cell offscreen. So if I return to that cell, the `progressView` has not been removed and the `imageView` has not been updated to a 1.0 alpha. Tried your same code there but it didn't seem to help there.

Comment: @NicHubbard: Perhaps you can update the question with the new code. But it is late now in Germany, so I will look at it tomorrow.

Comment: @NicHubbard: The "data sources" self.itemPaths and self.progressItems must be updated in any case in the blocks. Only changing the cell properties must be protected by the indexPath check. I have updated the answer (again not compiler-checked) with what I think it should look like.

Comment: I used this solution, but I don't start the download when cell is clicked so the progressView on other cells stops moving. How would I fix that?

Comment: @MartinR why not use the built in `__weak` and `__strong` to prevent the block from strongly capturing the cell?

Comment: @sbru: That won't help because the *table view* already retains the cell (by putting it on the reuse queue). The problem is not that the block keeps a *strong* reference to the cell but that the cell  might be at a different position when the block is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is only refer to the cell once at the beginning of your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, and create a property to keep track of the selected indexPath and the value of the progress indicator. The method below works, but I had to create a dummy slow method to test it out, so I hope you can see how to adapt this to your problem.

```
@interface TableController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *theData;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSIndexPath *downloadingCellPath;
@property (nonatomic) float progValue;
@end

@implementation TableController

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    if ([self.downloadingCellPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        cell.progView.hidden = NO;
    }else{
        cell.progView.hidden = YES;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    self.downloadingCellPath = indexPath;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    [self longMethod:indexPath];
}


-(void)longMethod:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    UIProgressView *activeProgressView = [(RDCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] progView];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        float x = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < 40000000; i++) {
            x = i * 3.14;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.progValue +=.01;
            activeProgressView.progress = self.progValue;
            if (self.progValue < .99){
                [self longMethod:indexPath];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"done");
                self.downloadingCellPath = nil;
                [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this won't work if the user wants tap more than one cell to start the download for those items.

Comment: @NicHubbard, well, in that case you need to keep an array of selected paths rather than a single item, and check if that array containsObject:indexPath.

Answer (score -1):

```
[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

    float totalProgress = (float)totalBytesRead/(float)totalBytesExpectedToRead;
    if ([[collectionView indexPathForCell:cell] isEqual:indexPath]) {
       cell.progressView.alpha = 1.0;
       cell.progressView.progress = totalProgress;
    }
}];
```